# How to get all loaded cells from UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with objects in cells that are in need of observers. When I navigate to another view, these observers needs to be removed. Will a call to `[tableView visibleCells]` get me all the currently *loaded* cells?

My cells are 3-400px in height, which leads to only 3-4 different cells being reused every time. At any point in time, two cells might be visible, or three cells might be visible. When I call `visibleCells` will I receive the ones **actually** visible on the screen, or will I receive all cells that have been through `cellForRowAtIndexPath` **that haven't been dequeued for reusing yet**?

The documentation simply states `Returns the table cells that are visible in the receiver.` ... `Return Value: An array containing UITableViewCell objects, each representing a visible cell in the receiving table view.`

Do they mean **visible** as in *actually* currently represented on the screen? Or visible as in that it is visible to the tableView, but not necessarily for the user (I.E not represented on the screen)?

Comment: Can you clarify ... are the `UITableView`s doing the observing or being observed for some reason?

Comment: @MikePollard The cells are observing their own instantiation of `AVPlayer`. The player and playerItem are being observed to be notified e.g to know the players playing-rate, or to know when the playerItem is ready to be played. When navigating away from the tableView I get a message in the log stating that an instance of AVPlayer was deallocated with an observer still attached, causing leaking (or unexpected behaviour etc.). I also had crashes happening when navigating, but unsure if these are connected. I'm trying to remove the observers the best way. Is it possible in table's -dealloc?

Comment: In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I create a new cell if it wasn't dequeued, and in this creation, I add an observer. (the players are also reused). I was wondering if I can call `[tableView visibleCells]` to get all individual cells that has been through the creation and started observing. Or if it's just the two-three (out of maybe 4) that are actually visible.

Comment: I'd put faith in `visibleCells` to return all the cells and see how you get on. (Of course you could test this by caching references to all created cells and compare with the results of `visibleCells`)

Comment: One question, if the cells are observing their own instantiation of AVPlayer then how come the AVPlayers are being dealloced? Won't the cells be holding a strong ref to them still?

Comment: @MikePollard I don't really know how deallocation works, but it seems like it works in an top-down kind of way. By logging out text in each `-(void)dealloc`, it seems like the viewController is deallocated first, then the tableView, then the cell. I don't know if this matters though.. I have never explicitly stated the deallocation of the AVPlayer. I have simply created the AVPlayer and  started observing it in the -init of the cell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60090/discussion-between-mike-pollard-and-sti).

Answer (score 3):

assuming `visibleCells` uses `indexPathsForVisibleRows` then it means visible(as on on-screen!) if it doesn't, thats still what it means BTW :D

there is no public method to get all LOADED cells Im afraid. What is hackisch but works(!) is enumerating the subviews of the tableView ;)

Comment: Hm.. The error I'm having is stating that an instance of the object was deallocated with observers attached. Can I simply just remove the observers in the cell's `dealloc`? I have no knowledge and a lot of mixed feelings about the entire release/dealloc-process as I'm a child of the new and ARC'y world, and have never really needed to release or deallocate or remove anything before..

Answer (score 1):

1) `visibleCells` returns just those visible to the user and there may be others that have been instantiated and are sitting in the 'queue'

2) `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` doesn't retain the observer and requires that you `removeObserver` before it gets dealloced. In your case I suggest you call `removeObserver` in the dealloc method of your custom `UITableViewCell`